# xPages-Notes-redirection-pagination : how to redirect to a certain page number of a paginated view?

Tags: redirect, pagination, xpages, lotus

I have a classical `xPage` with view panel (in a custom control) linked to a paginated view, which displays records.

I have more than one page to display. Each one has a key column defined as a link which sends the document to a form edition page.

Then in this page I update the record clicking a 'Save button' which redirects the user to the original view page (which URL has been stored in the sessionScope).

The problem is that it redirects to the first page and not the one which contained the record.

How can I specify the page number to display when coming back to the view page ?

Comment: Have a look at the Pager Save State control from the Extension Library. It automatically keeps track of the page you were on before entering a document.

Answer (score 0):

I had to do something similar for one of my applications and instead of using the simple action to redirect to the XPage I used the context.redirectToPage which allowed me to pass the sessionScope variable I had stored with the below code.

```
var url:XSPUrl;
URL = context.getUrl();
sessionScope.put('your scope name',@RightBack(url.getPath().toString(),"/"));
```

Comment: Problem solved : you must use "context.redirectToPrevious()" and not "context.redirectToPage(<URL>);